# window.center().open(); is off centered after the first call

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am opening a window with javascript using

```
var otherWin = $("#wndOther").data("kendoWindow");
otherWin.center().open();
```

I later close the window with javascript in a different function using

```
var otherWin = $("#wndOther").data("kendoWindow");
otherWin.close();
```

The problem that I am having is after the first time I open and close this window, when I go to open it again using the same method, it appears off centered to the right.

I would like for the window to be perfectly center every time. Does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a dojo or fiddle ? Which version are you using ? Do you have other windows that do not have the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, I was able to conclude that this is a bug in jQuery version 3.1.1 or later. If you don't want to upgrade your version of jQuery, you can turn off the animations for the window and it should work properly.

Example -

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("wndOther").Title("")
.Animation(false)  @* SET ANIMATION TO FALSE *@
.Content("<div id='otherInfo'></div>").Visible(false).Width(500))
```